# Is "phrase" an ambiguous term to use in a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Unless I've forgotten everything about English, the term "phrase" seems to cover two concepts:

1. A combination of words to make up a noun, such as [coal plant](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6053/54).
2. A fairly fixed combination of words that is almost an entire sentence, or is an  entire sentence, such as [thank you in advance](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/666/thank-you-in-advance-how-to-replace)

Does that make the term ambiguous? If so, does that make the tag [phrase-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request) a bit ambiguous, leaving question-askers confused as to whether they should use the tag or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not; rather, I think it could refer to either of those things. The tag wiki says:

> This tag is for questions seeking a phrase that fits a meaning. If you are looking for a word, or don't care, see the "word-request" tag too.

The idea, then: if you have a concept or idea, and want to know how to express it in English, you either want a single-word response or one longer than that. If you want a single word, use [word-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-request). If you want something longer, use [phrase-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request).

As a side note, I'm not sure I agree with the tag wiki when it says we ought to be double-tagging questions with both [word-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-request) and [phrase-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request). But I suppose that's another meta discussion!

(Also I believe your definition #1 is specifically referred to as a *noun phrase*. I think in practice, if a user requests a *word* and only a *noun phrase* is available, they weren't going to know that from the start, so they lack this knowledge to decide which tag to use.  Either way I don't think it's a big deal; if you request a word and only a phrase exists, someone will tell you, and vice versa. :) )

Comment: We need a hypernym! To [ELU we go](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypernyms)!